# PSD specifications help

Tags: format, specifications, psd

I'm writing a program (in Python for now) for reading PSD files. I'm using this specification: http://www.fileformat.info/format/psd/egff.htm
Here it says

> BYTE Name[];   /* Even-length Pascal-format string, 2 bytes or longer
>   */

Um, 2 bytes or longer? How am I supposed to find out how ling it is? I don't know what "Pascal-format string" means either.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Heres a direct link to the official PSD specification (pdf): http://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2923119-45984/Photoshop%20File%20Formats.pdf;jsessionid=21F2DBA32AB9E56882065663C10A1EBF.node0
Look in page 9, under "Image Resource Blocks"

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

"Pascal-format string" could mean string that have length encoded on first position IIRC.